# How to enforce a parameter to be a const?

Tags: objective-c

I have declared a few string constant in a .h file:

```
extern NSString *const kServiceName1;
extern NSString *const kServiceName2;
```

And assigned values to them in the .m file:

```
NSString *const kServiceName1 = @"service1";
NSString *const kServiceName2 = @"service2";
```

I now have a method declaration which takes one of these service name constants as a parameter, and I would like to enforce it to always take a const. Something like:

```
- (BOOL)serviceHasProfileUrl:(NSString const*)serviceName;
```

However, even if I manage to enforce it to be a const, it doesn't prevent me from passing in constants that are not service names. What I'm really after is a sort of enum with strings, or a way to define some `ServiceName` type which has several string values that can be called as constants.

I started off with a normal enum, but in the end I need the service names to be proper strings, as this is the representation required in the database, and if there is a simple solution, would remove a lot of the complexity around serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's not possible to create an `enum` of strings, then why not use a normal `enum`?  There seems to be no advantage in representing the service as a string anyway.

```
typedef enum {
    Service1,
    Service2
} Service;

- (BOOL)serviceHasProfileUrl:(Service)service;
```

**EDIT** (after question edit):

There is no reason to use strings just because that's how the service is represented in some external system.

Instead provide a mapping whereever that external representation is required:

```
NSDictionary *serviceDatabaseMapping = @{
   @(Service1): @"service1database",
   @(Service2): @"service2database"
};

NSString *databaseMapping = serviceDatabaseMapping[service];
```

Comment: @Elise OK, updated.  Actually you might need to tweak that dictionary as it's not clear to me at the moment if `@(enum)` will work without the compiler moaning.